# Python UTF-8 Latin-1 displays wrong character

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode, latin1

I'm writing a very small script that can convert latin-1 characters into unicode (I'm a complete beginner in Python).

I tried a method like this:

```
def latin1_to_unicode(character):

    uni = character.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")
    retutn uni
```

It works fine for characters that are not specific to the latin-1 set, but if I try the following example:

```
print latin1_to_Unicode('å')
```

It returns `Ã¥` instead of `å`. Same goes for other letters like `æ` and `ø`.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?
Thanks

I have the `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` declaration in my script, if it matters any to the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source code is encoded to UTF-8, but you are decoding the data as Latin-1. Don't do that, you are creating a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Decode from UTF-8 instead, and *don't encode again*. `print` will write to `sys.stdout` which will have been configured with your terminal or console codec (detected when Python starts).

My terminal is configured for UTF-8, so when I enter the `å` character in my terminal, UTF-8 data is produced:

```
>>> 'å'
'\xc3\xa5'
>>> 'å'.decode('latin1')
u'\xc3\xa5'
>>> print 'å'.decode('latin1')
Ã¥
```

You can see that the character uses *two bytes*; when saving your Python source with an editor configured to use UTF-8, Python reads the exact same bytes from disk to put into your bytestring.

Decoding those two bytes as Latin-1 produces two Unicode codepoints corresponding to the Latin-1 codec.

You probably want to do some studying on the difference between Unicode and encodings, and how that relates to Python:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, the solution works and it appears I have some studying to do!